# Reason for と particle after adverb さっき in sentence about something previously mentioned

Tags: verbs, particle-と, adverbs

I came across this sentence and I believe I understand what it is saying, but I don't understand why there is a と particle being used after さっき. Why is it not just さっき言ってる? As there is nothing that comes after さっき here

Sentence:

> 何？　さっきと言ってることが違う！
>
> What? That is different from what I was saying a moment ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A phrase is abbreviated, and it would be easy to figure out why "と" is required.

> さっき「言ってたこと」と言ってることが違う！

So, the sentence is comparing さっき「言ってたこと」 and 言ってること, so that it requires と.

That sentence is often used when someone is complaining/accusing that one changes his/her explanation.

Comment: I definitely would have not thought of that. Its makes sense though. These と particles are rough. Thanks!